# Comparing retention time of acetic acid, salicylic acid and acetylsalicylic acid in HPLC

Tags: chromatography

I want to compare retention time of acetic acid(AA), salicylic acid(SA) and acetylsalicylic acid(ASA) in HPLC. What are the factors do I have to consider when comparing? Considering dipole moment only, retention time would be AA(1.74D) < SA(2.65D) < ASA(6.49D). Is this correct? (Addition : Mobile phase would be water)

Comment: It very depends on character of the stationary mobile phase, that can point out particular type of interaction ( dipole, e. p. donor or acceptor ) or suppress it. By other words, at the same elution time of chosen analyte, elution times  of other analytes change with changed MF, or they can even switch the order.

Comment: HPLC does not do separations on the basis of dipole moments or so-called polarity. In fact, you will not see any retention of these very hydrophilic molecules on a typical C18 column. If you add more details, I can try to address your query.

Comment: See related [HPLC MP triangle](https://community.asdlib.org/imageandvideoexchangeforum/2013/08/02/using-a-solvent-triangle-to-optimize-an-hplc-separation/) on context of aromatic carboxylic acids on C18 column ( acetic acid would have probably just minimal retention).